# Sanity Test on Oracle Upgrade Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

My oracle sever has been upgraded from `Oracle 10g` to `12c`. DBA has created a box for that now my question is how developers will perform testing on that..
    Can anyone provide me the sanity or unit test document or scripts for an oracle upgrade database with respect to developer perspective.

Comment: may you please provide more information, what do you need to test? test if the upgrade is completed without error?

Comment: Before pointing to new database server what type of testing we need to perform means any code or performance metrics we should validate

Comment: Usually higher Oracle versions have added more security function, i.e. some functions which worked in version 10 are not working anymore in 12 unless you grant according permission explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your development or testing team already has a set of regression test cases, you are out of luck.  The possible things to test are astronomical.  Now, as others have pointed out, there are some things to look out for, like more restrictive privileges, and reviewing the "What's New" for both 11g and 12c.

One big example from the past that burnt a lot of people (including me) was upgrading from 9i to 10g; where developers relied on a "group by" clause in a select would always return the results sorted by the group by columns in 9i, but not always in 10g.  Not a bug; the SQL standard for group by says nothing about ordering of results; so a lot of code broke.  But again, only way to flush out those types of things are good regression test cases.

Now, after all that, I have not seen or heard about any 10g to 12c surprises, but there are a lot of wonderful new features that should be used when moving to  12c.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you want to test Oracle 12c itself but if the applications still function. In that case I propose that the developers (or test team) perform there 'normal' application tests to see if the applications still function correct.

The only thing that the DBA might give is information on the differences between Oracle10g and Oracle 12c at the handling of the data at SQL-level.

Comment: No need to validate code or performance level or is there any deprecated features from oracle 10g to 12c w.r.t plsql code

Comment: You probably want to read 'New Features' guide.